# What causes this golang os.Exec behavior (escaped double quotes)?

Tags: go, wget

I have the following code:

```
for i := 0; i < 1; i++ {
    wait := rand.Int63n(150) + 300
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * time.Duration(wait))
    //
    useragent := "--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS armv7l 8872.76.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.105 Safari/537.36'"
    outDirectory := "--output-document=temp/review-" + strconv.Itoa(i) + ".html"
    header := "--header=\"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8\""
    uri := "https://play.google.com/store/getreviews"
    payload := "--post-data=id=fi.danskebank.mobilepay&reviewSortOrder=2&xhr=1&reviewType=0&pageNum=" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    cmd := exec.Command("wget", useragent, outDirectory, header, uri, payload)
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(cmd.Args, " "))
    bytes, _ := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
fmt.Println("Finished crawling")
```

If I change the payload line from

```
payload := "--post-data=id=fi.danskebank.mobilepay&reviewSortOrder=2&xhr=1&reviewType=0&pageNum=" + strconv.Itoa(i)
```

to

```
payload := "--post-data=\"id=fi.danskebank.mobilepay&reviewSortOrder=2&xhr=1&reviewType=0&pageNum=" + strconv.Itoa(i) + "\""
```

It will return Server Error 500, even though when running the corresponding `wget`:

```
wget --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS armv7l 8872.76.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.105 Safari/537.36' --output-document=temp/review-0.html --header="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" https://play.google.com/store/getreviews --post-data="id=fi.danskebank.mobilepay&reviewSortOrder=2&xhr=1&reviewType=0&pageNum=0"
```

It will have same response as the post-data without escaped quotes.

Why does Golang os.Exec result in this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure what "bug" you're referring to. In one case you're executing `wget` through a shell, which will interpret quotes for you, and in the other you are executing a binary directly, which doesn't lex the arguments like a shell. These are two different things, so you're essentially asking "why does a shell parse quotes like a shell?

Comment: Yes, that is the case; edited the question so that it doesn't suggest this is a Golang feature or a bug. Considered deleting the question, but then again someone might end up with similar misconsideration as I did. In case people think, that this is not helpful question-answer, maybe we should delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute the command in your shell, the shell processes the quotes *and they aren't passed to the program you're executing*. When you execute a command in Go, there is no shell processing involved, so the quotes are passed through. Since the program isn't expecting them, they get passed through directly in the request body, and the server responds with an error.

Unrelated to your issue, but if you don't have a specific reason to use wget, you'd get far better performance using the [built-in HTTP client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) than forking out to wget for every request.

Comment: Thanks; didn't think about "not having a shell in-between" thing.

I was using wget, since the performance is not that important in many cases, as websites have requests per second limits. Instead by building "wget scripts" I can share them with people, who are not using Golang. So in a sense I am experimenting with a programming language agnostic scraping process: wget (uri + params) -> jQuery like HTML processor -> json.

Depending on wget and jQuery style configuration and a declarative program to interpret those, would allow wider reusability. But in the end I am just coding for fun.